# treetableview суммирование значений в главной ветке

Tags: java, javafx, java-hashmap

У меня есть treetableview:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Который я заполняю вот таким вот кодом:

```
 Connection Map = DatabaseHandler.getDbConnection();
        PreparedStatement FirstMap = Map.prepareStatement(MapInf);
        ResultSet rs = FirstMap.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String category = rs.getString(1);
            String name_score = rs.getString(2);
            BigDecimal difference = new BigDecimal(rs.getString(3));
            amount = amount.add(difference, mc);

            if (results.containsKey(category)) {
                Map<Expences, List<Expences>> innerMap = results.get(category);
                innerMap.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().add(new Expences(category, 
name_score, difference));
            }
            else {
                Map<Expences, List<Expences>> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
                innerMap.put(new Expences(category, category, total), new ArrayList<>());
                innerMap.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().add(new Expences(category, 
name_score, BigDecimal.ZERO));
                results.put(category, innerMap);
            }
```

Мне нужно реализовать вот это:
1 - создается главная ветвь "Расходы"
2 - условием проверяется есть ли в созданном мапе полученная из бд категория
3* - если категории нет, то создаём категорию с total = 0.
4 - Находим категорию внутри map
5 - увеличиваем сумму категории на сумму текущей операции

Я пытаюсь сделать последние два шага вот таким кодом:

```
Map<Expences, List<Expences>> Summ = results.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue();
            BigDecimal Sum = Summ.entrySet().iterator().next().getKey().getDifference();
            Expences a = new Expences();
            a.addEntry(Sum);
```

Но у меня вылетает NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION.

Класс Expenxces:

```
public class Expences {
private String category;
private String name_of_score;
private BigDecimal difference;
private BigDecimal total;
private List<Expences> entries = new ArrayList<>();

public Expences() {
}

public Expences addEntry (BigDecimal expence) {
    this.total = total.add(expence);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: `this.total = total.add(expence);`. В поле `total` `null` хранится ибо вы не присвоили полю никакого объекта.

Comment: Дээээ, глупая ошибка(... суммирую bigdecimal который изначально пустой

Answer (score 0):

Вот эта часть кода работает не правильно:

```
Map<Expences, List<Expences>> Summ = results.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue();
        BigDecimal Sum = Summ.entrySet().iterator().next().getKey().getDifference();
        Expences a = new Expences();
        a.addEntry(Sum);
```

Нужно написать вот так:

```
 Map.Entry<Expences, List<Expences>> innerMap = 
results.get(category).entrySet().iterator().next();
    innerMap.getKey().setTotal(innerMap.getKey().getTotal().add(difference));
```